# 3D nonogram – Name the object

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

This is a 3D nonogram. The first five boxes represent the five layers of a $5\times5\times5$ cube, and the last box shows the enumerations for the Z-axis. (Note that 11 means two stretches of length one here, not one of length eleven.)

To increase the difficulty somewhat, a few of the numbers have been replaced with question marks. A question mark simply means that the number of shaded cells in that row or column is unknown.

> [image]

Name the geometric object that appears in six different forms in the grid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The shapes are

> hexominoes

The filled grids are

> [image]

You get the shapes by

> looking at the connected cubes
>  [image]

Comment: This is correct. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Hexominoes, but with cubes instead of squares.

[image: “natural view”]

The sheets:

[image]